# Is a carried person "gear" for the purpose of Invisibility and Gaseous Form?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, invisibility

If I'm carrying a person and use Gaseous Form or Invisibility, is the person I'm carrying also transformed or made invisible?

If no, what if the person is inside a big bag?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31319/8610).

Answer (score 2):

Both spells affect 1 creature and all its "gear". The word "gear" is used inconsistently throughout the rules: sometimes it includes armour and sometimes not, sometimes it includes clothes and sometimes not, sometimes it includes weapons and sometimes not, etc. What it **never** includes is another creature.

The person inside the bag (if they are alive) is a creature, when you go gaseous the bag joins you and they fall to the floor. If you go invisible than they appear to be floating in the invisible bag.

If they are dead, then there is an argument that they are "gear": DM's call.

If they are in an extra-dimensional space (e.g. Bag of Holding) then they stay in that space.

Comment: I'm not sure i agree, turning someone invisible shouldnt reveal wether or not he's smuggling kobolds in his backpack to sell as miners the other side of the border.   
How is a kobold different than a loaf of bread? or a potted plant? or from live leeches or flies which could be used as material components? Any caster who'd want to cast a spell with living components couldnt cast invisibility?

Comment: A kobold is different in that it qualifies as "creature" and flies or leeches qualify as "vermin". We need to make that distinction or we couldn't turn invisible at all with all these bacteria on our skin. Thats not how this works. As to the distinction of creatures from vermin, especially thinking of these beings coming in *all* sizes in RPGs, just ask your DM. I'd call anything with it's own mind and will a creature.